# How to call search engines in c++ or java code

Tags: java, c++, search-engine

I intend to write a program that will search multiple search engines simultaneously, and give the results in a nice GUI interface.  However, I am unsure how to handle this in code.  Namely, how to perform the search and then store the results.

I am not looking to build my own search engine.  I mostly want to reuse other search engines results to make finding what I am looking for easier.

Note, the language I am using is either C++ or Java.  However, if examples exist in other languages that could be translated to these languages, I would appreciate said examples!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the right way to go but anyways something for u to look at. If dont want to use the api from for instance yahoo, google or bing i suppose html scraping is a alternate way to go perhaps?.

Not sure about this but its a start to look at. [Options for HTML scraping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping)

And i suppose u can find some terms of use or policies from the search engines about this to make it troubled..